# next.js renders another template on <Link> click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I've noticed that my next.js application renders a different template when I call a page by clicking on a  component than when I call the page directly.

This is my folder structure (pages-Folder):

```
[posttype]
    index.js
[...uri].js
index.js
```

Since I'm working with the SSG, I generate the paths at build time:

```
// [...uri].js

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = [
        {params: {uri: ["about"]}},
        {params: {uri: ["projects"]}},
    ]

    return {
        paths: paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}

// [posttype]/index.js

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = [
        {params: {posttype: "posts"}},
        {params: {posttype: "articles"}},
    ]

    return {
        paths: paths,
        fallback: false
    }
}
```

If I now call the page `/about/` directly (via the address bar of the browser), the template `[...uri].js` is rendered. However, when I call the page via a link component, the template `[posttype]/index.js` is rendered, which is not correct.

[I've created a sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/routing-fail-v2-n2kylw)